# How do I resolve the [onhold] status added to my question?

Tags: support

My question, "[Quantification of Frequency Adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160586/quantification-of-frequency-adverbs)" - is marked as [onhold] with this info-box:

> **put on hold as primarily opinion-based by tchrist, medica, choster,
>   David M, MrHen 21 hours ago**
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the
>   [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/160586/edit) or leave a comment.

While I would be happy to leave a comment on the question itself, it is unclear if the parties that flagged the question would be notified, and more importantly, in my opinion, that would be a poor platform for responding to the matter.

I have attempted to search the meta-questions of English.SE for "[onhold](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=onhold)" and was unable to find any existing information of use; in fact, there were zero results for the topic.

Further, while I understand that a number of parties agreed on the topic, to my knowledge not one posted an explanation of why they believed either the question somehow solicited, requested, or asked for opinions - or would only result in opinion-based answers.

How do I resolve the [onhold] status added to my question?

Comment: I'm not sure why people saw that post as primarily opinion-based, but several folks have already voted to reopen without even editing it. The original table appears to be based on somebody's unfounded opinion, but the question and its answers are not. (And I think there's a little value in debunking a bogus ESL reference.)

Comment: +1 @Bradd Szonye: Agree, guessing that people who voted to close the question did not even read the question; or the answers for that matter.

Comment: Your question is open again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Onhold' is the new nicer name for 'closed'.

To get it reopened, you should edit your question and then either

1) hope that people notice and decide to vote to reopen, or

2) canvas for reopen votes, either in comments, or in chat

Answer (score 4):

"On hold" is a new designation for closed questions that are pending improvement. Once you edit your question, it will automatically move into a review queue for our 3K+ users to consider it for reopening.

Comment: Make that [“for our 3K+ users”](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).